# Can we map tuple entries into object type

Tags: typescript

Suppose we have values represented by type

```
type Values = [{ ref: "a" }, { ref: "b" }, { ref: "c" }];
```

And we want a function that can produce an object of these values given a field to key them by. Is there a way to represent the resulting type given the tuple values and key? For example I got this, but, though the keys are correct, the values are unions of all tuple values.

```
type MapTuple<
  T extends readonly Record<PropertyKey, unknown>[],
  K extends keyof T[number],
> = {
  [I in keyof T as K extends keyof T[I] ? T[I][K] & PropertyKey : never]: T[I];
};
```

```
type Test = MapTuple<Values,"ref">
```

resolves to

```
{
    a: {
        ref: "a";
    } | {
        ref: "b";
    } | {
        ref: "c";
    };
    b: {
        ref: "a";
    } | {
        ref: "b";
    } | {
        ref: "c";
    };
    c: {
        ref: "a";
    } | {
        ref: "b";
    } | {
        ref: "c";
    };
}
```

Would like a type that resolves to

```
{
    a: {
        ref: "a";
    };
    b: {
        ref: "b";
    };
    c: {
        ref: "c";
    };
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=6&pln=7&pc=80#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QM5QLxQNoG8oBOEAZgFxQBEcFUAvgDRT5FmUBGNDThJ5FAxpwC6AbgBQY0JCgBZOGAAqSMAggAeMVCgKoEAB7AIAOwAm6InBMB7IwhBQAShH5WCJtQAUCVyAVABpCBBGJCMAayMrAHcjAD5sIXpNKH9dA2MzKDCgq2JtbCMkAFs2CAJEsVjMJmTsAEkoAEsjLJy8nTh0VP1DU3RskFz8uqEoAH5hoWx-UYAyKC8fMoCgqHIjCAA3MqFyBXrRMVpxCSloBTRgarlFZVU1eGQ0egoWCligA)

Comment: What is the result supposed to be?

Comment: You could "do the reverse", deriving the array type from the key type and it would work: https://tsplay.dev/N7QOGW

Comment: Nice one, works great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal change to get your version working would be to make sure that `I` doesn't iterate over `number` itself.  Otherwise, when `I` is `number`, then `T[I]` is the union of the element types.  You can do so by [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `keyof T` with `` `${number}` ``, which should give you only the known numberlike indices of the tuple (so, `"0" | "1" | "2"` in the case of `Values`):

```
type MapTuple<
    T extends readonly Record<PropertyKey, unknown>[],
    K extends keyof T[number],
> = { [I in `${number}` & keyof T as
        K extends keyof T[I] ? T[I][K] & PropertyKey : never]: T[I];
    };

/* type Test = {
    a: {
        ref: "a";
    };
    b: {
        ref: "b";
    };
    c: {
        ref: "c";
    };
} */
```

Personally though instead of iterating over `keyof T`, I'd iterate over `T[number]` and use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to extract the key like this:

```
type MapTuple<
    T extends readonly Record<K, PropertyKey>[],
    K extends PropertyKey,
> = { [U in T[number] as U[K]]: U };
```

That gives the same result but is significantly more concise.

[Playgound link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAegVMAuCeAOCmACAsgQ1gFQK6wDbwB5hETENF4APSeAOwBMBnRAJ3lXoHtbdpEAleAGNOLegQAKLTghYwA0vGgAaRFloBrWpwDutAHwBtALrLipeRWp0miDUs4AzModpYAtgCN4LU8H2IALyIAN6IhgCSiACWtIgABgAkIW5ePgC+8YgAZHYOzuSojOakFlY0DMz20E4uEcaIAPx1xobyDblSMj4KSogAXIi08ABuPsaDGJHGANwliOlzYCBQcEhomDj4RKXkVBW2bBzcvALCouLyql2yvdBGfqWW+zbMNz3Qiir+QaHhAKoxOJTVLeXyIIqIf5tYwTKELOarBCIABqqFwWHgzGChjCbEcgwARKhCQtVHj4ATEITPKT0uTWJSiUI6bMkUgMFjIL8Ntg8IQ0RisapCfjCfo5iAQKQAHqNIA)

Answer (score 1):

You could try having `T` be defined in terms of `K` instead to get around key remapping:

```
type MapTuple<
  T extends readonly Record<K, PropertyKey>[],
  K extends PropertyKey,
> = {
  [P in T[number][K]]: Extract<T[number], Record<K, P>>;
};
```

Then you can extract the right value from the array using the key's value.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QM5QLxQNoG8oBOEAZgFxQBEcFUAvgDRT5FmUBGNDThJ5FAxpwC6AbgBQY0JCgBZOGAAqSMAggAeMVCgKoEAB7AIAOwAm6InBMB7IwhBQAShH5WCJtQGlGABQJXIBKAeECAAfNhC9JpQHroGxmZQvv4QgSDBIFGhmEzR2N5QAJZG2thGSAC2bKlC2B5CQuQAogYEcPzAagplldUEkY7Oru5eSaGh4rTiElLQCmjAOXKKyqpq8MhojBQsFKFAA)

Answer (score 1):

- your `T` only needs to be a `Record<K, PropertyKey>[]`
- your `K` may be still `keyof T[number]`. Recursion is allowed here.
- you can iterate with `in` over any union type, so `T[number]` is fine

```
type Values = [{ ref: "a" }, { ref: "b" }, { ref: "c" }];

type MapTuple<
  T extends { readonly [P in K]: PropertyKey }[],
  K extends keyof T[number],
> = {
    [P in T[number] as P[K]]: P;
  };

type Test = MapTuple<Values, "ref">
```